# How to reset the Flex HTML control's history

Tags: apache-flex, air

I am using the flex HTML component and I would like to clear the history of the control when it is taken off screen, so that when it comes back on again the history is reset.

The only thing I can think of at the moment is to set the HTML control to a new HTML control, although this is a bit of a pain.

Thanks

Comment: Setting the states autoDestructionPolicy to auto and then switching the states between one which doesn't have the html control in makes this easier.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML control has a property named historyLength and 
[historyPosition](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/HTML.html#historyLength) properties.  Both allude to fact that the HTML content has a window history.

I bet you can use the [domWindow](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/HTML.html#domWindow) property to get, and empty the history object.

```
htmlObject.domWindow.window.history
```

More info on the history object [here](http://docs.sun.com/source/816-6408-10/history.htm).  Nothing says it is read only, so I bet:

```
htmlObject.domWindow.window.history = new Array();
```

But I'm half guessing; I didn't try this code.